# Why does link tooltip disappear the moment I take my mouse off of the link symbol in the toolbar?

Tags: quill

To test links in my Quilljs editor, I'm highlighting text and then clicking the link symbol in the toolbar -- for a split second the link tooltip shows up, only to disappear right away unless I hold my click on the symbol.

It appears that there's a 'ql-hidden' class that's being applied wrongly, but I'm not sure if it's something to do with my configuration being incorrect.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var primaryQuill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: {
            toolbar: '#toolbar',
            'link-tooltip': true
        },
        theme: 'snow'
});
```

Here's the HTML (using the Jade templating language):

```
#toolbar
    span.ql-format-group
        button.ql-bold(type="button") Bold
        button.ql-italic(type="button") Italic
    span.ql-format-group
        button.ql-link(type="button") Link
#editor
    p Start writing here...
```

And here are the only styles I've written for this:

```
.ql-toolbar {
    background: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1) !important;
    margin: 5px 0px !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.ql-container {
    margin: -5px 0px !important;
    background: #fff !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    min-height: 500px;
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Quill 1.0 beta or an older version?

Comment: @jhchen I'm using v1.0.0-beta.2

Comment: Can you use the playground http://beta.quilljs.com/playground/ to demonstrate this? There's nothing obviously wrong with your configuration and it works when I try so it would seem other parts of the app is interfering. The most recent beta includes link-tooltip for you when you use the snow theme btw.